# Is there any way to update a label in C# without using a timer?

Tags: c#, label

I am trying to make a label update automatically, but since in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight I can't use a timer, I have to do it in a different way.

Comment: you want to update the label as a result of what?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Please improve little bit your question anyway...why you can't use a timer? Why not? Moreover don't forget you may also use an Animation timer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Task or Threading something like this

```
private async Task ChangeLabel()
{
   while(true)
   {
      await Task.Delay(100)
      label1.Text = "lorem impus";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a in depth example

```
label.Text = "Your text here";
```